# Git clone without including top/parent folder

Tags: linux, git

We have a repo in git where the project is contained in a folder called Project. We'd like to be able to release the code to a production server, by cloning the repo, without including the "Project" folder, but with everything below it. Is this possible? The destination directory name is /var/www, which is unrelated to anything in the project.  Unfortunately I can't just do a symbolic link because of the nature of our hosting provider (which we'll change soon).

Comment: just try ``git clone Project /var/www``

Comment: I don't want to include the Project folder in the clone process. Instead of /var/www/Project/index.html I'd rather /var/www/index.html

Comment: cd into your Project folder, run `git init`, `git add .`, `git commit -a` and then clone that to your production server. Would that accomplish what you want?

Comment: It would. I was just hoping there was more of a "git" way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

My answer take the assumption that you have a git repository whose content is the following:

```
/.gitignore 
/Project
/Project/index.php
/ProjectB
/ProjectB/pom.xml
```

If you don't need history at all in that copy of your repository, there is the `git archive` command which can do what you want except its output its data in `tar` or `zip` format:

```
git archive [--format=<fmt>] [--list] [--prefix=<prefix>/] [<extra>]
              [-o <file> | --output=<file>] [--worktree-attributes]
              [--remote=<repo> [--exec=<git-upload-archive>]] <tree-ish>
              [<path>…]
```

Like:

```
git archive --format=zip --remote=git@foobar.git master -- Project | unzip
```

However, the git clone command does not accept a repository path, and I think it's not really git like to export only a tree view of some branch. You would probably need a submodule making Project an independent git repository, or like the `git archive` example, get only what you want but without versioning (which can be questionable on a production server).

Instead, you can do that:

- Clone your repository to whatever path, say `/opt/foobar`.
- Create a symbolic link of `/opt/foobar/Project` in `/var/www`.

Or reference the `/opt/foobar/Project` in your apache configuration (to avoid the symlink) instead of plain `/var/www`.